# UISegmentedcontrol with multiple selection

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uiswitch

I need to create a custom UISegmented control that supports multiple selection, I need to know what segments are selected and when they change from selected to not selected. Im using this to turn feeds of data in my app on and off, you can have multiple feeds of data turned on at the same time.

I can't find any tutorials or info on how to do this!!

this library has the functionality i want, but i can't customize the appearance enough (i just want it to be a thin colored line, a different color for every selected segment)
https://github.com/attheodo/ATHMultiSelectionSegmentedControl

I need to customize it to look like this

[image]

When a feed is selected the colored bar should show up, and when it is unselected it should go away

any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't use segmented control, thats not how it's supposed to work. You will be better off just adding many UIButtons changing their image on tap.

Comment: How would I track which buttons are selected so I know what feeds to turn on?

Comment: Got any examples you could point me to?

Comment: With flags in your view controller.